# iterator of template based container

Tags: c++

```
template<class A,class B>
void tmp(){
    set<int,int>::iterator it; //works
    set<A,B>::iterator it; // doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to some rather annoying limitations in C++'s grammar, you must explicitly tell C++ that `set<A,B>::iterator` is a type name, rather than a static member identifier, using the `typename` keyword. For example, this code compiles just fine:

```
#include <set>

template<class A, class B>
void tmp() {
    std::set<int,int>::iterator x; // OK
    typename std::set<A,B>::iterator it; // Also OK
}

int main() {
    tmp<int,int>();
    return 0;
}
```

This occurs because C++ requires that the compiler make a final decision as to whether to interpret `set<A,B>::iterator` as a type or as a variable/function when it's parsing the grammar; *before* the template is instantiated. However, prior to template instantiation, it is impossible to make that determination, as in the general case this may depend on the values of `A` and `B`. As such, the compiler will assume it to be a variable/function unless explicitly stated otherwise. This then results in a parse error.

Comment: "Even while using typename before set::ite... I can't make iterator of template based container."...

Comment: @easyonesorry, works for me, with your exact code altered to add the `typename` (and variable names changed to not be the same, and a call added to instantiate `tmp()`)